# Compute Mutliplication of complex numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, multiplication, complex-numbers

What I am trying to do ultimately is multiplying two complex numbers like this:

```
z1 = R1 + I1*j

z2 = R2 + I2*j

z3 = z1 * z2 = (R1*R2 - I1*I2) (R1*I2 + R2*I1)*j;
```

But what I have are two separate vectors for the real and complex part of both those complex numbers. So something like this:

```
v1 = [R1, R2, R3, R4 ... Rn] of z1

v2 = [I1, I2, I3, I4 ... In] of z1

v1 = [R1, R2, R3, R4 ... Rn] of z2

v2 = [I1, I2, I3, I4 ... In] of z2
```

So when I am trying to calculate z3 now, I do this:

```
foo (std::vector<double> real1, std::vector<double> imag1,
     std::vector<double> real2, std::vector<double> imag2)
{
    std::vector<double> realResult;
    std::vector<double> imagResult;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < real1.size(); i++)
    {
         realResult.push_back(real1[i]*real2[i] - imag1[i]*imag2[i]);
         imagResult.push_back(real1[i]*imag2[i] + real2[i]*imag1[i]);
    }

    //And so on
}
```

Now, this function is eating a lot of time. There sure is another way of doing that can you think of something that I can use?

Comment: Preallocate the result vectors and fill them in, rather than using push_back

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to make use of [std::complex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex). This probably implements operations you require at least close to as well as they can be implemented.

EDIT (In reply to comment):

I would do this:

```
size_t num_items = real1.size();
std::vector<double> realResult;
realResult.reserve(num_items);
std::vector<double> imagResult;
imagResult.reserve(num_items);
for (size_t i = 0; i < num_items; ++i) {
  // lalala not re-sizeing any vectors yey!
  realResult.push_back(real1[i] * real2[i] - imag1[i] * imag2[i]);
  imagResult.push_back(real1[i] * imag2[i] + real2[i] * imag1[i]);

}
```

Otherwise if you have a large input array and you are doing a lot of multiplication on doubles I'm afraid that might just be slow. Best you can do is mess around with getting things contiguous in memory for bonus cache points. Impossible to really say without profiling the code exactly what might work best.

Comment: As above. I will give it a shot but I would need to populate std::complex with my vectors. Do you know a way to effeciently do that?

Comment: @FreddyKay I suspect you would find it was all a lot faster if you initialize the result vector to the size you expect it to be, or `reserve` that space. I would have to profile to be sure but I would suspect looking at that code that a fair amount of time might be used up re-allocating more space for the result vectors. I'll edit my answer to show this suggestion.

Comment: @FreddyKay populating the complex numbers could be done following the same ideas of reserving the space first and just looping. I would suggest that if possible you simply initialize your original data as a vector of std::compex to avoid the extra copy.

Comment: @FreddyKay Also I got the first edit totally wrong, hopefully now I have produced an example that actually works!

Answer (score 3):

Pass in parameter as `const std::vector<double>&` to avoid unnecessary copy

You may also consider computing each multiplication in parallel, if `N` is big enough, the overhead of parallel computing is worthwhile

Comment: Obviously. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) of [`std::complex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex). It is simple and optimized for arithmetic operations

```
foo(std::valarray<std::complex<double>> & z1, 
    std::valarray<std::complex<double>> & z2) 
{
    auto z3 = z1 * z2;  // applies to each element of two valarrays, or a valarray and a value 

    // . . .
}
```

**EDIT**: Convert vectors to valarray

```
std::valarray<std::complex<double>> z1(real1.size());
for (size_t i = 0; i < z1.size(); ++i)
    z1[i] = std::complex<double>(real1[i], imag1[i]);
```

Comment: This seems nice. I will give it a shot. Although I would have to fill the arrays effeciently with my vectors. Do you have a suggestion there?

Comment: @FreddyKay added in the answer.